# Cocoa: Anomaly Writing TAB Character to File?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

I'm using the following to define an NSString containing the Tab character:

```
#define TAB @"\t"
```

I'm writing a longer NSString to a file using writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error, using encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding. This longer NSString contains TAB characters.

When I open the resulting file in TextEdit, I see a character that looks like a Japanese glyph in the place of the TAB character. Here is a screen shot of a line that is intended to have two tab characters, but which has these odd characters instead:

[odd characters http://www.market-research-services.com/starpowermedia/for_distribution/tab-char-anomaly.png](http://www.market-research-services.com/starpowermedia/for_distribution/tab-char-anomaly.png)

What is the correct way to #define an NSString that will contain a TAB character to be written to a file of NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: can you give a small full example that I can compile.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do that via #define? With stringWithFormat and the \t as format string it works well.